# Is c# a suitable language for Chatterbot development which involve in Natural Language processing?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, aiml

I am doing my final year project and  at the beginning of developing a chatter-bot mostly based on ALICE techniques.I have done research comparing two main chatter-bot systems ELIZA and ALICE and selected ALICE method of developing the chatter-bot.

The knowledge base will be developed using AIML and the searching algorithms will be used as ALICE where searching with wildcards "_","atomic words", and "*".

I have selected c# for the developing of needed algorithms and user string manipulation, and also as my chatter-bot is web based it is easy to deal with web development as well with c#.net.The already written API is also available.

My Problem is:

Whether the choice of selecting c#.net is good???

What are the possibilities of finding help with the development of a chatterbot with c#.net???

Other solutions for my situation???

Looking forward for you valuable suggestions. Thank you very much.

:):)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a meta language such as ANTLR ([www.antlr.org](http://www.antlr.org)) would work for you. You specify the natural language grammar to lex, parse and respond to according to your AI rules using the ANTLR language. Then use the ANTLR code generator to output the C# (or Java) code that implements your custom parser.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a new answer to a very old question, but it might help future generations.

[Program#](http://aimlbot.sourceforge.net/) is an AIML interpreter written in C#

> AIMLBot (Program#) is a small, fast, standards-compliant yet easily customizable implementation of an AIML (Artificial Intelligence Markup Language) based chatter bot in C#.

So to answer the question: Yes, C# is a suitable language for Chatterbot development.